# Is there a publicly accessible map of the Swedish medium-voltage electricity grid?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government, europe, energy

I am aware of [Open Infrastructure Map](https://openinframap.org/#6.13/57.227/14.383/L,P,S) - it does a great job of showing electric power lines. I would like to have a datasource independent from OIM, showing the Swedish electricity grid, possibly with substations.

I am also aware of [this](https://www.svk.se/en/national-grid/map-of-the-national-grid/) map - I need higher resolution though. [This map](https://www.entsoe.eu/data/map/) shows the locations connected, but the power lines itself are not marked with precision. I can use [this map](https://vbk.lansstyrelsen.se/) to confirm OIM's map of high voltage power lines, but that map has only the highest voltage lines, and not the lower level ones.

[This map](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/electric-power-transmission-lines/explore?location=37.704023%2C-96.422940%2C9.00) is about the US. I would need a similar one but of Sweden.

Comment: I was looking foward to find some answers here... did you find what you are looking for? I am searching also data about substations and low voltage grid. until now the best source was OpenstreetMap

Answer (score 3):

Open Infrastructure Map is based on OSM Data. Let's use it to create own map / dataset. In below example I'm using R and mainly `osmdata` together with `sf` packages.

Let's download the boundary of Sweden, which will be used as a clipping area.

```
sw <- osmdata::getbb("Sweden", featuretype = "country", format_out = "matrix") |>
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 60) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "2") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

boundary <- sw$osm_multipolygons |>
  subset(name.en == "Sweden") |>
  sf::st_geometry()

boundary |>
  plot(col = "grey90")
```

Let's download all features with `power` key (for details, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:power):

```
p <- osmdata::getbb("Sweden", featuretype = "country", format_out = "matrix") |>
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 600) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "power") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()
```

Now, we will extract only power lines, which spatially belong to Sweden. They are in `osm_lines` data:

```
grid <- p$osm_lines |>
  subset(apply(sf::st_intersects(p$osm_lines, boundary, sparse = TRUE), 1, any)) |>
  subset(power == "line") |>
  subset(select = c("osm_id", "voltage")) |>
  tidyr::separate_rows(voltage) |>
  dplyr::distinct(.keep_all = TRUE) |>
  dplyr::mutate(voltage = as.numeric(voltage))
```

And let's add them to the plot:

```
plot(grid["voltage"], add = TRUE)
```

Let's extract the substations form `osm_polygon` and `osm_multipolygon` data, bind them together and add to plot as well:

```
subst <- p$osm_polygons |>
  subset(apply(sf::st_intersects(p$osm_polygons, boundary, sparse = TRUE), 1, any)) |>
  subset(power == "substation") |>
  subset(select = c("osm_id", "name"))

subst <- p$osm_multipolygons |>
  subset(apply(sf::st_intersects(p$osm_multipolygons, boundary, sparse = TRUE), 1, any)) |>
  subset(power == "substation") |>
  subset(select = c("osm_id", "name")) |>
  rbind(subst)

subst |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(col = "grey90", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

The downloaded data can be saved on disc for further use with `st_write()` function from `sf` package. Then you can open it in QGIS and style it properly.

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>