# Germany Transmission Network

Tags: data-request, geospatial, energy, germany

Is there any source to find the high voltage (110kV and above) substation and transmission network for Germany.

I have tried contacting the Transmission System Operators but have only got generic responses back.

For the substations a list of coordinates would be ideal but even a static map that could be geo-referenced in would work.

Any ideas as google searches have started to fail me.

Comment: Please have a look on my answer under https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19973/is-there-a-publicly-accessible-map-of-the-swedish-medium-voltage-electricity-gri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [openmod wiki](https://wiki.openmod-initiative.org/wiki/Transmission_network_datasets), which lists currently available sources.

The appropriateness of sources depends on the details of your use case. For example, if you are happy with quantitative transmission capacities between "reasonable" grid nodes, you could go for the input data of the open source [ELMOD-DE](https://www.diw.de/de/diw_01.c.599753.de/modelle.html#ab_599760). If you require full geographical detail, your best bet is likely to pull the data from OpenStreetMap and do some postprocessing: Check out [this](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/53691/how-to-download-electricity-distributiontransmission-lines-data-for-an-us-state) discussion concerning the extraction of distribution/transmission lines. Substations would be analogous. To the best of my knowledge, that's what most models rely as original input. Don't count on the TSOs ;)